# how can i do Multiple Request using Promise.all using this parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

today I had some problems with my code.. the thing is I have to create a multiple POST request to the API to pass users to a group, so.. the API request is:

```
POST /users/user-group-membership

{
  "userId": "string",
  "groupId": 0,
  "isActive": true,
}
```

Basically i have to grab from the users table the userId from each user and for each userId create a multiple request... so what i did was:

```
const moveTogroup = async (
  token: string,
  userId: string,
  groupId: number,
): Promise<any> => {
  const res = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${API}/users/user-group-membership`,
    data: { userId: userId, groupId: groupId },
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });
  const { data } = res;
  return data;
};

export const moveAllGroup = (
  token: string,
): ThunkAction<void, State, null, UsersActions> => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { userId, groupId } = getState().FleetUsers;
    const convert = userId.toString();
    console.log(convert);
    dispatch(moveUserToGroupRequest());
    try {
      const userPromises = userId.map(() =>
        moveTogroup(token, convert, groupId),
      );
      const move = await Promise.all(userPromises);
      console.log('moving:', move);
      dispatch(moveUserToGroupSuccess(move));
      Swal.fire('Saved', 'Your Changes has been saved', 'success');
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(moveUserToGroupFailure(error));
      Swal.fire('Error', error, 'error');
    }
  };
};
```

But as you see this only works for one userId, I grabbing from the state the userId and the groupId, converting the userId to string, and voila is working perfectly, only what I want is depending how much userId I have in the state replied to the request for creating multiple requests and when the user selects in table 2 or 3 users, he or she can move them easily.

Comment: I don't really understand how you retrieve userIds, does `getState().FleetUsers` contains all users as it suggest? however result is stored in `userId` suggesting a single user

Comment: @JeanBouvattier yes, getState().FleetUsers contains all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your userId var contains all userIds, you must map it to recover specific information about each userId :

```
userId.map((elt) => {
    const convert = elt.toString();
    moveTogroup(token, convert, groupId),
});
```